SIGSEGV with with MPZ_Class and acutest
I am new to c++ programming and to improve I wanted to make an implementation of the bleichenbacher attack. I have prior built one in python and thought it would make a good exercise to learn c++ a bit.
To use large number I found the gmp library. I am trying to write unit tests as I go so i can be sure that everything works correctly. For the unit tests I am using acutest.
The problem currently arises that I get a "TEST INTERRUPTED BY SIGSEGV" when I try to do too many statements?
So the test here works:
void createRSA(void) {
  gmp_randstate_ptr state;
  gmp_randinit_default(state);
  RSA rsa1(state);
  RSA rsa2(state);
  RSA rsa3(state);
  RSA rsa4(state);
  // RSA rsa5(state);
}

But if I wanted to create one more RSA Object i get the SIGSEGV. Similarily this test also fails if i uncomment the last line:
void createRSA(void) {
  gmp_randstate_ptr state;
  gmp_randinit_default(state);
  RSA rsa(state);

  mpz_class d = rsa.getD();
  mpz_class e = rsa.getE();
  mpz_class n = rsa.getN();

  TEST_ASSERT(((mpz_sizeinbase(n.get_mpz_t(), 2) + 7) / 8) == 128);
  TEST_ASSERT(((mpz_sizeinbase(n.get_mpz_t(), 2) + 7) / 8) == 128);
  TEST_ASSERT(rsa.getE() == 65537);
  // RSA rsa2(state);
}

The RSA class is also very simple:
class RSA {
private:
  mpz_class e, d, n;
public:
  RSA(gmp_randstate_ptr state);
  getE() { return e; };
  getD() { return d; };
  getN() { return n; };
}

#include "rsa.hpp"
#include "gmp.h"
#include "gmpxx.h"

RSA::RSA(gmp_randstate_ptr state) {
  // create rsa pair and set the values
  mpz_t p, q, E, D, N, x, y, phi, u, t, gcd;
  mpz_inits(p, q, E, D, N, x, y, phi, u, t, gcd, NULL);
  mpz_set_ui(E, 65537);

  mpz_setbit(u, 511);
  mpz_setbit(t, 512);

  mpz_urandomb(x, state, 512);
  mpz_add(x, x, u);
  mpz_mod(x, x, t);
  mpz_urandomb(y, state, 512);
  mpz_add(y, y, u);
  mpz_mod(y, y, t);
  mpz_nextprime(p, x);
  mpz_nextprime(q, y);

  mpz_mul(N, p, q);

  int k = (mpz_sizeinbase(N, 2) + 7) / 8;

  while (k != 128) {
    mpz_urandomb(x, state, 512);
    mpz_add(x, x, u);
    mpz_mod(x, x, t);
    mpz_urandomb(y, state, 512);
    mpz_add(y, y, u);
    mpz_mod(y, y, t);
    mpz_nextprime(p, x);
    mpz_nextprime(q, y);

    mpz_mul(N, p, q);

    k = (mpz_sizeinbase(N, 2) + 7) / 8;
  }

  mpz_sub_ui(p, p, 1);
  mpz_sub_ui(q, q, 1);
  mpz_mul(phi, p, q);
  mpz_gcd(gcd, E, phi);

  int res = mpz_invert(D, E, phi);

  if (res == 0) {
    printf("Failed to compute inverse of e!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  e = mpz_class(E);
  d = mpz_class(D);
  n = mpz_class(N);

  mpz_clears(p, q, E, D, N, x, y, phi, u, t, gcd, NULL);
}

The constructor calculates a valid rsa pair and then sets the private fields.
I really am at a loss here as to why the test just starts failing at some point.
If anyone has any ideas any help is greatly appreciated!
I tried several different test methods to find out where it exactly goes wrong, but I could not pinpoint the point of failure. The tests also fail when I create 3 RSA objects and read more than 2 fields. So a test that creates two objects and then compares the n fields of both objects PASSES, but if I added a third object to that test and also try to read the n field of that object I get the SIGSEGV.
I also made a very simple Constructor where I literally just set the fields to a set number:
RSA::RSA(gmp_randstate_ptr state) {
  e = mpz_class(1); // the wrapper is not needed but also without I get SIGSEGV
  d = mpz_class(2);
  n = mpz_class(4);
}

But even then I get a SIGSEGV so I really have no clue what else I could do.

SIGSEGV (aka segmentation fault) simply means that your program tried to access memory outside it's allocated address space. That's usually caused by a buffer overflow, dereferencing an invalid pointer or similar. So look for memory addressing bugs in your code. Tools like address sanitizer may help.

Thanks for the tipps!
I used the address sanitizer and found the problem was with the gmp_randstate.  All I had to do was clear the states at the end of the tests and now everything works fine! Now I can create as many objects as I want in the tests :D
Thanks again for the help.
void createRSA(void) {
  gmp_randstate_ptr state;
  gmp_randinit_default(state);
  RSA rsa(state);

  mpz_class d = rsa.getD();
  mpz_class e = rsa.getE();
  mpz_class n = rsa.getN();

  TEST_ASSERT(((mpz_sizeinbase(n.get_mpz_t(), 2) + 7) / 8) == 128);
  TEST_ASSERT(((mpz_sizeinbase(n.get_mpz_t(), 2) + 7) / 8) == 128);
  TEST_ASSERT(rsa.getE() == 65537);
  // RSA rsa2(state);
  mpz_randclear(state); // <- this line fixed it

}

In hindsight a very simple fix but just couldnt find it before so thanks!
